# I am trying to use Django paginator with HTML, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, django

I am trying to use pagination in one of my learning projects which is an Ecommerce website. I am trying to load products on the Products page. I followed the django docs tutorial and some youtube. The paginator works like the page 1,2 etc but on all the pages it show every product while I specified in views.py on three.

views.py

```
def store(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    products = Product.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(products, 3)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {'products': products,
               'cartItems': cartItems, 'paginator': page_obj}
    return render(request, 'store/products.html', context)
```

products.html:

```
 <!--Pagination-->
      <div class="container p-4">
        <div class="pagination justify-content-center">
          <span class="step-links">
            {% if paginator.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ paginator.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
              Page {{ paginator.number }} of {{ paginator.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>

            {% if paginator.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ paginator.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ paginator.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
            {% endif %}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end of Pagination-->
```

Comment: How do you access the `Product` objects in the template? Do you loop through `products` or `page_obj.object_list`?

Comment: Yes it was through ```products``` loop. But as soon as I posted this question I fixed it but changing the ```products``` in html loop to the page_obj and it was good to go. Thanks!